# Iphone safari browser taking lot of time to render charts in a dashboard

Tags: javascript, iphone, highcharts

I have developed a webpage containing charts using [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). It works fine on the PC safari browser, but takes a long  tim to load on an iPhone. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

propably the highcharts library. JavaScript on the iPhone is not nearly as fast as on a desktop. You should take a look at this:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/iphone-javascript-and-spec-benchmark

Here you can see that the iPhone 2G was almost 65 times slower as the macbook. And also the iPhone 3GS and 4 are faster, they're not nearly as fast as a desktop computer.

Comment: yea , that's definitely is the case. can u please recommend any low resource taking js libraries for iphone . thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it so slow, because the iPhone is not fast as your computer.
Maybe take a look at other graphing libraries like [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/). It is based on [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), which is used in [Sencha touch](http://g.raphaeljs.com/), a JavaScript library for mobile devices and is maybe more optimized.

Comment: gRaphael has no documentation buddy ...how do i get started. the google group is not much help either and can u please recommend any low resource taking js libraries for iphone . thanks

Comment: I never used it, but I heard a lot of good things about this library, thats why I said "maybe take a look" and not "you should use"...